# Trying to have a variable auto increment (+1) within my stored procedure that already has a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create insert an incremental value  to insert into a column called HR_NUM. This HR_NUM value should increase everytime I create a new entry that meets the grouping criteria in my cursor (c1). I also don't want to put it inside my cursor because I don't want to group by that number as that will throw my groupings off. Thanks and please let me know if im missing anything and/or if i can clarify/edit anything.

I know the for loop syntax for oracle is:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
    date_test date;
BEGIN
    select sysdate into date_test from dual;
FOR i in 1..24 
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(date_test + i/24);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Below is my current plsql code that I am trying to incorporate a loop in to auto increment HR_NUM: (the HR_NUM variable is in **BOLD)**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SUM_HOURLY IS
  Cursor c1 is
select 
sum(value_tx) AS sum_of_Values
, ff.form_field_tx
, ff.form_field_id
, (CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END)     as HR_CONVERTED_PST
, to_char(to_date((CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END),  'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'dddyyyy') as DATA_DATE
, v.DATA_CODE
from value v
join submission_value sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
join form_field ff on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
group by (CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END), 
         to_char(to_date((CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END),  'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'dddyyyy'), ff.form_field_id, ff.form_field_tx, v.data_code,;
-----------
  l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
  v_value_id value.value_id%type;
-----------
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
LOOP
  FETCH c1 into l_var;
  EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        insert into value (value_id, energy_product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt)
              values (null, '109', '269', 'Mwh', l_var.sum_of_values, 0, l_var.data_date, 'UTC0', l_var.HR_CONVERTED_PST, **incremental_Variable(?)**, 'NA', sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null)
END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
END SUM_HOURLY;
```

Comment: Can't you just use a sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this just a simple INSERT statement ?  Saves a lot on coding effort:

```
insert into value (value_id, energy_product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt)
select null, '109', '269', 'Mwh', sum_of_values, 0, data_date, 'UTC0', HR_CONVERTED_PST, rownum, 'NA', sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null)
from
(
select 
  sum(value_tx) AS sum_of_Values
, ff.form_field_tx
, ff.form_field_id
, (CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END)     as HR_CONVERTED_PST
, to_char(to_date((CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END),  'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'dddyyyy') as DATA_DATE
, v.DATA_CODE
from value v
join submission_value sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
join form_field ff on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
group by (CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END), 
         to_char(to_date((CASE WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 4 
        THEN HR - 3/24 
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 5
        THEN HR - 2/24
        WHEN UTC_OFFSET = 6
        THEN HR - 1/24
         END),  'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'dddyyyy'), ff.form_field_id, ff.form_field_tx, v.data_code
ORDER BY [[you should have something here]]
);
```

Comment: what i need is the hour number (Nth Hour) taken from the hh24 value from the HR timestamp. so for example if it was 20:00:00 i want HR_NUM 20 regardless of what time zone it is in before the conversion (if that makes sense)im thinking there is some function that pulls just the value for Hour?

Comment: to_number(to_char(hr,'HH24'))

Answer (score 1):

Create a sequence below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_hr_num
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  NOORDER;
```

In the insert, use 'seq_hr_num.nextval' to replace '**incremental_Variable(?)**'.

Comment: oh, the catch is i need it to stop at 24 and recycle based off how many entries i have that meet the group by criteria (i.e. 1:00:00 AM in PST is HR_NUM = 1,  4:00:00 AM in PST is HR_NUM = 1 in a Eastern Time zone) if that makes sense